# Working procedure of RAND() in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, mysql5

i'm trying to select 5 rows randomly from my table using RAND() in mysql, and i've set the LIMIT as 5 but why sometimes it will return less than 5 rows?

Here is my Query:

```
SELECT id from MAIL where RAND() limit 5;
```

MAIL is my table name which contains more than 20 Records.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL select 10 random rows from 600K rows fast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4329396/mysql-select-10-random-rows-from-600k-rows-fast)

Comment: ORDER BY not WHERE

Comment: ORDER BY giving the 5 records. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In your version of the use of `rand()` function, MySQL evaluates its result in a Boolean context because it is directly used in the `where` clause, not in the `order by` clause.

If `rand()` is evaluated as false, then the record is left out of the resultset. It is possible that in a particular query more than 15 records are eliminated as a result of this approach resulting in less than 5 records being returned.

Your should use the `order by rand()` clause to overcome this issue.